# The HTML button on mobile is not centered as desktop view

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I created a web which contained with 2 buttons. On desktop view, it is okay and locate centered.
But on mobile view, they shift to the left.
What should I do on CSS to make them locate centered on desktop and mobile?

I tried to amend `style = "margin-left: 5%;` to 10%. But it makes the two buttons shift to the right on desktop.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12" style = "margin-left: 5%;">
<button type="button" id="lost_item_button" class="btn btn-primary " onclick = "lost()" >A</button>


<button type="button"  style = "background-color: #fefefe;color: #0a0a0a;display:none" id = "found_button_selected" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" onclick = "found()">B</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Margin and use the text-center class should do rest.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center">
   Content/Buttons
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap div "text-center" as

```
<div class=" col-md-4 col-xs-12 text-center"> <button type="button" id="lost_item_button" class="btn btn-primary " onclick = "lost()" >A</button>
```

B

or remove the margin-left to margin only.